# How to display button and status bar items in line

Tags: odoo

How to display below mentioned two group(marked in red circle) in line?

[image]

relevant code for the same is given below

```
     <header>
                <button name="mymod_assigned"  class="oe_highlight" type="workflow" string="Assigned"   state="new" />
                <button name="mymod_negotiation" class="oe_highlight" type="workflow" string="In Negotiation" state="assigned"  />
                <button name="mymod_won" class="oe_highlight" type="workflow" string="Won" state="negotiating"/>
                <button name="mymod_lost" class="oe_highlight" type="workflow" string="Lost" state="negotiating"/>
                <field name="state"  widget="statusbar"
                      statusbar_visible="new,assigned,negotiation,won,lost"
                      statusbar_colors='{
                                        "new":"blue",
                                        "assigned":"blue",
                                        "negotiation":"blue",
                                        "won":"red",
                                        "lost":"red"
                                        }'
                                         />
        </header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting left group of buttons in one div with `float:left` and right group in another div with `float:right`.

Comment: Thanks Cakan .  Just added above code under one div without adding any float.